# python locale currency to 0 decimals

Tags: python, format, decimal, locale

I can't figure out how to set my currency to 0 decimals. for now it always puts .00 behind my currency.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
damn = locale.currency(self.damn, grouping=True).replace('$','') + " Dmn"
```

self.damn is always an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are just interested in grouping. You don't need to use the currency function for this. Use `locale.format()`:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
damn = '{0} Dmn'.format(locale.format('%d', self.damn, True))
```

And if you don't depend on the `locale` stuff, you can group the number with `string.format()`, too:

```
# Comma as separator
damn = '{:,} Dmn'.format(self.damn)
# Locale aware separator
damn = '{:n} Dmn'.format(self.damn)
```

Comment: You should use ``"{}".format()`` instead of ``+`` to concatenate strings.

Comment: This is not equivalent as `format` will not take into account the proper grouping for currencies. For example set locale like `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_PT')` and then try `'{:n}'.format(10500587463)` vs `locale.currency(10500587463, grouping=True)`

Answer (score 1):

The output is a string so add [:-3] to the end it:

```py
a = locale.currency(num, grouping=True)[:-3]
```